# Leaflet- marker click event works fine but methods of the class are undefined in the callback function

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, onclick, leaflet, gis

I'm using the following code to add a callback function to the `click` event for some leaflet markers (of which I do not know the number a priori):

```js
newArray.forEach(p => {
  let marker = L.marker(latLng).on('click', this.markerClick).addTo(newMap)
  marker.bindPopup(content)
  marker.addTo(newMap)
  marker.openPopup()
})
```

And in the class there is the function `markerClick` that does this:

```js
markerClick(e) {
  console.log("Inside marker click " + e.latlng.lat + "  " + e.latlng.lng)
  this.displayError("You clicked on the marker")
}
```

The `console.log` is printing correctly the values of `lat` and `lng` of the marker, but when calling `displayError` a runtime error is thrown saying that:

> this.displayError is not a function

This is a function declared in class that I use to show a toast with a custom message, accordingly to what I need.  This is the code:

```js
displayError(messageErr: string) {
  let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
    message: messageErr,
    duration: 3000,
    position: 'top'
  });
  toast.present();
}
```

Why is saying that is not a function?

EDIT: it is not just `displayError`, every function of the class gives this message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a classic JavaScript mistake.

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in JavaScript does not necessarily refer to your class instance object. It is the *context* of the function *when it is called*.

You can force this context with [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), and in many libraries you can easily force it as well. In this case with Leaflet you can pass a 3rd argument to [`on`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#evented-on) when attaching your event listener:

```js
// Force current `this` to be the context when `this.markerClick` is called
marker.on('click', this.markerClick, this);
```

With `bind` it would be:

```js
marker.on('click', this.markerClick.bind(this));
```

And there is also the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) solution, which uses the context / value of `this` *where the arrow function is defined*, rather than where it will be called:

```js
marker.on('click', (event) => this.markerClick(event));
```