# Leaflet cant display div when mouseover marker

Tags: typescript, leaflet, angular5

I would like to do a method that will display me in the bottom right corner of the div with information about the marker when I hover over the marker with the mouse

All in typescript.

It is detected to move the mouse over the marker (the console correctly prints the message) but the info item does not create.

error :

```
core.js:1440 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_controlCorners' of undefined
    at NewClass.addTo (leaflet-src.js:4620)
    at NewClass.eval (osm-generator.component.ts:73)
    at NewClass.fire (leaflet-src.js:588)
    at NewClass._fireDOMEvent (leaflet-src.js:4272)
    at NewClass._handleDOMEvent (leaflet-src.js:4229)
    at HTMLDivElement.handler (leaflet-src.js:2231)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4724)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
```

code:

```
let info = L.control.attribution({position: "bottomright"});

          info.onAdd = function () {
            let div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'),
              labels = [];

            labels.push('<div class="information-section">Informations</div>');

            div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');

            return div;
          };

          marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            marker.openPopup();

            info.addTo(this.map);

          });
          marker.on('mouseout', function () {
            marker.closePopup();
          });
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170860/leaflet-marker-click-event-works-fine-but-methods-of-the-class-are-undefined-in/48172254#48172254

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a quick search in Leaflet's source code will show that the only place that `_controlCorners` is accessed is at [this line of code](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/14c5f1602cdd337df14c37ea8df777578219f744/src/control/Control.js#L72):

```
// @method addTo(map: Map): this
// Adds the control to the given map.
addTo: function (map) {
    // [stuff]
    var corner = map._controlCorners[pos];
    // [stuff]
},
```

It seems that you're adding a control to a non-initialized map, or otherwise the parameter to the `addTo()` call is not a map. I suggest you start by `console.log()`ing the value of `map` in your calls to `addTo(map)`.

Answer (score 0):

working version ,('this') after function resolve it.

```
let info = L.control.attribution({position: "bottomright"});

          info.onAdd = function () {
            let div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info'),
              labels = [];

            labels.push('<div class="information-section">Informations</div>');

            div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');

            return div;
          };

          marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            marker.openPopup();

            info.addTo(this.map);

          });
          marker.on('mouseout', function () {
            marker.closePopup();
          }, this );
```