# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined Leaflet and VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, leaflet

I am making a vue project and I want to use leaflet inside of my components. I got the map showing but I run into an error when I try to add a marker. I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined

and

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'latlng' of undefined

I think it's because I'm not setting my map bounds correctly?

```
<template>
<div id="app" class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <div id="map" @click="onClick" class="map" style="height: 781px;">
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <!-- The layer checkboxes go here -->
  </div>
</div>

<router-view/>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "App",
data() {
return {
  map: null,
  marker: null,
  mapSW: [0, 4096],
  mapNE: [4096, 0]   
 },
mounted() {
  this.initMap();
  this.onClick();
},
methods: {
initMap() {
  this.map = L.map("map").setView([0, 0], 1);
  this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer("/static/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
    maxZoom: 4,
    minZoom: 3,
    continuousWorld: false,
    noWrap: true,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
  });
  this.tileLayer.addTo(this.map);
  // this.map.unproject(this.mapSW, this.map.getMaxZoom());
  // this.map.unproject(this.mapNW, this.map.getMaxZoom());
  this.map.setMaxBounds(
    L.LatLngBounds(L.latLng(this.mapSW), L.latLng(this.mapNW))
  );
},
onClick(e) {
  this.marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
    draggable: true
  }).addTo(this.map);
  }
  }
};
 </script>
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code do I see any attempt to access a `lat` property of anything

Comment: @Phil that is within the call to Leaflet's `L.marker(e.latlng)`. This shows that it is much better for OP to include the full error stack trace, rather than just the final error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `onClick` listener is called on Vue's `@click="onClick"` attribute of your DOM map container. Therefore it receives a [plain `"click"` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click), which does not have the Leaflet's [`latlng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#mouseevent-latlng) added property.

Since you want to do something on the map and not directly on its container, then you probably meant to listen to Leaflet's map [`"click"`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-click) event. In that case, you can simply attach your listener with:

```js
this.map.on('click', onClick, this);
```

(you can attach it typically just after you initialize your map)

Note that it will greatly help you binding the `this` context by using the 3rd argument of Leaflet's [`on`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#evented-on), otherwise `this` in your listener will refer to something else than your Vue component instance (see [Leaflet- marker click event works fine but methods of the class are undefined in the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170860/leaflet-marker-click-event-works-fine-but-methods-of-the-class-are-undefined-in/48172254#48172254))