# Ionic leaflet moveend triggered function not found

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, leaflet, dom-events

I'm currently working on a ionic 3 project with leaflet. 
I want to trigger a function after moveend (or dragend) but it would not reconize the function I'm triggering. It says it is not declared.

Error I'm getting:

> 'this.functiontoload is not a function'.

Hopefully someone is able to help.

```
loadmap(){
    this.map = L.map('map', {rotate: true, touchRotate: true, zoomControl: false}).fitWorld();
    L.tileLayer('https://maps.tilehosting.com/styles/streets/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=XXXX', {
        attribution: 'Projectname',
        crossOrigin: true
    }).addTo(this.map);


    this.map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 20});

    this.userMarker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09], {icon: this.userMarkerIcon}).addTo(this.map);

    let watch = this.geolocation.watchPosition();
    watch.subscribe((data) => {
        let latitude = data.coords.latitude;
        let longitude = data.coords.longitude;

        var newPosition = L.latLng(latitude, longitude);

        this.userMarker.setLatLng(newPosition);
    });


    this.map.on('moveend', function() {
        this.functiontoload();
    });

}

functiontoload() {
....
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Leaflet- marker click event works fine but methods of the class are undefined in the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170860/leaflet-marker-click-event-works-fine-but-methods-of-the-class-are-undefined-in)

Comment: Thanks Ghybs, my problem was slightly different, because I tried to fire a function from a button in the popup instead of pressing the marker. However I dropped the popup and used the method of the url you provided.

Answer (score 2):

It just about "this." meaning in your call back function and It isn't about leaflet.
you can use arrow function or pass "this" to your function
so you can change your code to:

```
 this.map.on('moveend', ()=> {
    this.functiontoload();
});
```

The motivation for a arrow function is:

-You don't need to keep typing function

-It lexically captures the meaning of this

-It lexically captures the meaning of arguments

Comment: Although this answer might resolve the problem. Providing only a solution isn't helping anyone. What was incorrect about the code of OP and why does your example resolve the issue?

Comment: I had same problem and It was about "=>" if you don't use lambda "this." is undefined. problem is about angular not about leaflet.

Comment: A lambda is just an anonymous function (including normal `function () {}` definitions). This is specifically about the new [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in ES6. Your explanation should be added to the answer, not as an answer to my comment. Keep in mind that the intent is that people reading your answer understand why this works (within the context of the question), so they don't stumble upon the same question again in the future.

Comment: @JohanWentholt. I add some extra information to answer.