# Using Prototypal Pattern with Creating a Leaflet Map: error with onEachFeature function

Tags: javascript, leaflet, prototypal-inheritance

I have the following code that I call to create a copy object of map, and initialize the Leaflet map. This works and loads properly. However, the onEachFeature and/or the clickFeature functions are not working properly.

```
var map = {
    mapUrl: "",
    maxZoom: 18,
    minZoom: 2,
    map: L.map('worldMap').setView([51.505, -0.09], 2),
    create: function(values) {
        var instance = Object.create(this);
        Object.keys(values).forEach(function(key) {
        instance[key] = values[key];
        });
        return instance;
    },
    initLeafletMap: function() {
        L.tileLayer(this.mapUrl, {
            attribution: '',
            maxZoom: this.maxZoom,
            minZoom: this.minZoom,
            id: 'mapbox.streets'
        }).addTo(this.map);
        //add continents' outlines
        $.getJSON("/static/continents.json", 
           (function(style, onEachFeature, map) {
                return function(continents) {
                    console.log(typeof(continents));
                    L.geoJson(continents, {
                        style: style,
                        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
                    }).addTo(map);
                };
            }(this.style, this.onEachFeature, this.map))
       );
    },
    style: function() {
        return {
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'beige',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0
        };
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            click: this.clickFeature
        });
    },
    clickFeature: function(e) {
            do something here();
    },
```

So when I click on the map, I know the onEachFeature function is called, but it does not call clickFeature. Instead I get this error in the console:

```
leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at e.fire (leaflet.js:5)
    at e._fireDOMEvent (leaflet.js:5)
    at e._handleDOMEvent (leaflet.js:5)
    at HTMLDivElement.r (leaflet.js:5)
```

Comment: Please user the non-minified `leaflet-src.js` file instead of `leaflet.js` - it will give you a more readable stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much probably simply need to bind the `this` context when you pass your `onEachFeature` method as argument of your IIFE to build the callback to your AJAX call:

```js
this.onEachFeature.bind(this)
```

See also [Leaflet- marker click event works fine but methods of the class are undefined in the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170860/leaflet-marker-click-event-works-fine-but-methods-of-the-class-are-undefined-in/48172254?r=SearchResults#48172254)

BTW you could also attach your click event listener directly on the Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group instead of doing it for each child layer.