# clear and add markers again using marker.remove()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet, maps

My goal : I want to remove markers from the map and redraw it using setinterval() to update position on the map.

Expected results : remove markers and redraw it again every 4sec.

Actual results : old markers is not removed and new markers are added on it over and over .

Error Massage : there is no Error message to include .

I tried to check if marker is not null and if not null to remove marker from the map (this.marker.remove()) I tried this.marker.removeLayer(this.map) . loop over all markers and remove it one by one or set markers to null .nothing worked . down here i will include the code . i would be happy for any help . thanks in advance .

`` new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        /* Data properties will go here */
        map: null,
        tileLayer: null,
        errored: false,
        xxx: [],
        selectedValue: null,
        marker: null,
        geocoder: null,
    },

```
computed: {

    onlyUnique() {

        return [...new Set(this.xxx.map((city => city.location.name)))];
    }

},

mounted() {
    /* Code to run when app is mounted */ // when the Vue app is booted up, this is run automatically.
    this.initMap();
  this.getData();
```

setInterval(this.getData,4000);

```
},

methods: {
    /* Any app-specific functions go here */
    initMap() {

        this.map = L.map('map', {
            center: [20.0, 5.0],
            minZoom: 2,
            zoom: 2
        });
        this.tileLayer = L.tileLayer(
            'https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>',
                subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']
            }
        );
        this.tileLayer.addTo(this.map);

    },

    onChange(event) {


        this.selectedValue = event.target.options[event.target.options.selectedIndex].text;
        this.geocoder = L.esri.Geocoding.geocodeService();

        this.geocoder.geocode().text(this.selectedValue).run((error, response) => {
            if (error) {
                return;
            }

            this.map.fitBounds(response.results[0].bounds);
        });

    },
    getData(){

      axios
        .get('url')
        .then(response => {this.xxx= response.data}).catch( error =>{
            // handle error
            console.log("//////ErroR//////");
            console.log(error);
            this.errored = true;
        });

        setTimeout (this.drawMarker,500);
    },
   drawMarker(){
     if (this.marker) {
               console.log(this.marker);
               this.marker.remove();
     }

     for (var i = 0; i < this.xxx.length; i++) {

     this.marker = new L.marker([this.xxx[i].location.gps.coordinates[1],this.xxx[i].location.gps.coordinates[0]])
    .bindPopup("hello")
    .addTo(this.map);

     }

    }
},
```

});```

Comment: Do you need to move your settimeout call  in the get data method to  inside the then block? It might be that you are trying to redraw before your axios call has returned. You can console.log the value of this.xxx just before you call settimeout to double check.

Comment: What is the length of the data you put in `this.xxx`?

Comment: Have you tried `marker.removeFrom(map)`? if you want to use `removeLayer` type this: `map.removeLayer(marker)`

Answer (score 0):

Probably a `this` context scope issue:

```js
setTimeout (this.drawMarker.bind(this), 500)
```

See also [Leaflet- marker click event works fine but methods of the class are undefined in the callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170860/leaflet-marker-click-event-works-fine-but-methods-of-the-class-are-undefined-in/48172254?r=SearchResults#48172254)

> This is a classic JavaScript mistake.
>
> `this` in JavaScript does not necessarily refer to your class instance object. It is the context of the function when it is called.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer but unfortunately , I tried it but it's not the problem :(